# Protect a .php file that will contain connection string

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, web-config

I have set up a little website that can be used to search a **mysql** database I have created. The problem is while testing the site I just hardcoded the connection string into each php page. Obviously this would be crazy to leave like this and so I researched into protecting the string.

I have concluded that I need to store the string inside a .php file and include it within each page that needs to connect. I have looked into many different ways of securing it but **none seem to apply to my current situation**.

**.htaccess** - Not applicable because I use **Windows Hosting**

**Moving outside of root** - My GoDaddy hosting **does not allow** extra folders outside of root (annoyingly)

I do however have **IIS 7** and have looked into creating a **web.config** file, however when I created one it blocked access to my entire website. I don't quite understand how to use the file.

Please can anyone suggest a way to protect my file **without using** the .htaccess or webroot, if the answer is to use the web.config file then please help me in setting it up!.

Thanks for any time that you spend helping me!

**Extra Info:**

The Website is stored in a directory named {ROOT}/DatabaseApp/PageOne.php etc

I moved the sqlconfig.php file to a directory inside this one named "Protected" ({ROOT}/DatabaseApp/Protected/sqlconfig.php)

Comment: There should be no application code in the DOCUMENT_ROOT. Only php file that exists in your DOCUMENT_ROOT should contain `include '../application/bootstrap.php';` or something similar. If your hosting does not provide that option, then **change the hosting**.

Comment: The site is only to be used by those in my home and the application does not contain any sensitive data. I have protected any passwords that are stored in the mysql database with a salt and md5 hash. Changing hosting right now would be a pain and I would just like a solution to protect the only real "sensitive" data, the connection string.

Comment: Solved, I have switched my hosting to Linux and will use .htaccess files. Thanks for any time spent reading this post.